# Recommended best practice for server naming

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We're currently in the process of upgrading to SQL Server 2012, in the past all servers have been installed with a naming convention which contains a "-" in the middle i.e. TS-DBL01

I'm trying to convince people that it would be better to remove this is, but I'm starting to question if it really is best practice to change this to TSDBL0.

Any advice welcome

Answer (score 1):

I would say, if you have a naming convention, stick to it. Having 3 naming conventions due to chaninging best naming conventions over time, is not OK.

Answer (score 1):

This is opinion based as there is no right or wrong way to do this. It depends on what will be best suited for your organization.

we generally have a standard that goes as below:

RegionCategoryUseTypeNumber

Region=which region the server is located e.g NY, FL

Category = Production, UAT, QC

Use=if internal or hosted

Type=database or webserver

Number= starts from 1 and moves on

for e.g. A production hosted database server located in Florida would be named as

FLPRDHOSTDB1

as a side note, I would stay away from any Hyphens or special characters or space from the name.

I agree with you that you should remove the hyphen from the name. Its just my way and other people might agree or disagree.